# More complex docpad metadata

Tags: templates, metadata, docpad

I'm new to docpad and a lot of the things which it's based upon, therefore sorry if this question might seem a bit dumb. So far docpad is the most designer-friendly one of the recent static site builder out there, that's why I even made it until here :) Thanks for the amazing documentation!

What I'd like to achieve is the following:

- setting up pages in a way that I can access different sections via the template (e.g. paragraph 1, table 1, paragraph 2)
- having a template which allows me to change the structure/order of the content of those pages (eg moving around the paragraphs on all of them by changing the template)

The metadata section sounded good for that, but it does not allow any markup languages in there, right? So where can I define those different "paragraphs" and how can I access them via the template?

Thanks, Philipp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you could do the following:

```
--- cson
someContent: """
    # h1
    p1
    """
---

<%- @document.someContent %>
```

And name the file `blah.html.md.eco` so render the eco first which wil inject someContent, then it will render with markdown, rendering someContent.

We also had `--- cson` to say use [CSON](https://github.com/bevry/cson) to parse the meta data rather than the standard YAML parser. I find CSON easier to write for more advanced things and multi-line inputs.

Alternatively for the rendering aspect, you can use the [text plugin](https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-text) to specify how pieces of content should be rendered like so:

```
--- cson
someContent: """
    <t render="md">
        # h1
        p1
    </t>
    """
---

<%- @document.someContent %>
```

Comment: That injects the `somecontent` in the `blah.html` directly. That's a first step, but ideally I'd like to inject it via the layout file `blah.html.eco`. And when I put `<%- @document.someContent %>` there  it renders the markdown syntax in the document instead of converting it. Also when I add .md in the filetype. Might still be a bit confused by the filetype hierarchy - thanks for helping out Benjamin!

Comment: Yep, so use the text plugin for that (the last code example) and it will render the markdown content, despite your layout not using the markdown extension, as the markdown content is wrapped in  <t render="md"> which is what the text plugin needs.

Comment: How come the YAML parser is stuggling with indents though? And shouldn't it be considered a bug? I have markup that parses perfectly fine in other YAML parsers which docpad wont except as valid metadata.